# Switching off InSequence

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have a mock class like this:

```
struct MockClass {
    MOCK_METHOD0(beginTransaction, void ());
    MOCK_METHOD0(doSomething, void ());
    MOCK_METHOD0(doSomethingElse, void ());
    MOCK_METHOD0(commit, void ());
};
```

I want to test whether `beginTransaction()` is called before calls to `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()`, and `commit()` is called at the end. I did it like this:

```
{
    InSequence s;
    EXPECT_CALL(*mockObject, beginTransaction());
    EXPECT_CALL(*mockObject, doSomething());
    EXPECT_CALL(*mockObject, doSomethingElse());
    EXPECT_CALL(*mockObject, commit());
}
```

This works, but it overspecifies the expectation. I don't care about the sequence of `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()`, only that `beginTransaction()` is called at the very beginning and `commit()` is called at the very end. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this work?  I haven't been able to test it out yet unfortunately.

```
Expectation e1 = EXPECT_CALL(*mockObject, beginTransaction());
Expectation e2 = EXPECT_CALL(*mockObject, doSomething()).Times(AnyNumber()).After(e1);
Expectation e3 = EXPECT_CALL(*mockObject, doSomethingElse()).Times(AnyNumber()).After(e1);
EXPECT_CALL(*mockObject, commit()).After(e1, e2, e3);
```

This basically says that `beginTransaction()` must be called, and it must happen before any other call.  And then `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse()` can be called any number of times (including 0).  Finally, `commit()` must be called after the calls to the other functions.